# how to calculate short path geodesic distance of adjacency matrix csv [python]?

Tags: python, csv, matrix, shortest-path, adjacency-matrix

i have an adjacency matrix of graph

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBom1.png)

> n 1 2  3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> 1 0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
>
> 2 1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
>
> 3 1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
>
> 4 1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0
>
> 5 0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0
>
> 6 0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   0
>
> 7 0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1
>
> 8 0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0
>
> 9 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0

how to convert it to geodesic discance matrix using python?

my goal is to make it like this :

> n  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
>
> 1 0   1   1   1   2   2   3   3   4
>
> 2 1   0   1   2   3   3   4   4   5
>
> 3 1   1   0   1   2   2   3   3   4
>
> 4 1   2   1   0   1   1   2   2   3
>
> 5 2   3   2   1   0   1   1   1   2
>
> 6 2   3   2   1   1   0   1   1   2
>
> 7 3   4   3   2   1   1   0   1   1
>
> 8 3   4   3   2   1   1   1   0   2
>
> 9 4   5   4   3   2   2   1   2   0

i've tried some code in networkx but it only can calculate at one source and one destination of (n) not the whole matrix. I really need your help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`networkx` can calculate the whole matrix. One just need not to give source or destination to the `nx.shortest_path` function (see https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html - last example). Here's my solution:

```
import pprint
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
mat = pd.read_csv('adjacency.csv', index_col=0, delim_whitespace=True).values
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(mat)
p = nx.shortest_path(G)
shortest_path_mat = np.zeros(mat.shape)
for i in range(mat.shape[0]):
    shortest_path_mat[i, :] = np.array([len(x) for x in p[i].values()])
pprint.pprint(shortest_path_mat-1)
```

adjacency.csv

```
n 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0

2 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

3 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

4 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0

5 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0

6 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0

7 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1

8 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0

9 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: I've installed networkx, pandas, numpy but still error

Comment: ` File "C:\Users\kikiegoguma\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\networkx\convert_matrix.py", line 487, in from_numpy_matrix
    "nx,ny=%s"%(A.shape,))
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: ('Adjacency matrix is not square.', 'nx,ny=(9, 0)') `

Comment: Maybe something is wrong in your `csv` file. Please put blank line between each line of values. You can not copy-paste it from here.