# Number of intermediate nodes in shortest path

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, shortest-path

I am calculating all the shortest paths in a weighted graph with the `csgraph` module from `scipy.sparse`

I have a matrix (`InputMatrix`) of N*N and I am using the following function:

```
DijstraMatrix, DijkstraPredecessors=sp.sparse.csgraph.shortest_path(InputMatrix, method="D", return_predecessors=True)
```

I think that because of efficiency reasons, the explicit paths are not returned by a list of predecessors for each node. And then the shortest path  between any two nodes i and j can be reconstructed from the `DijkstraPredecessors` list.

My problem is that I need the shortest path that maximizes the number of visited nodes. If I implement a reconstruction for a big matrix, it takes forever to calculate all the reconstructed paths.

The function is somehow calculating that information internally.. is there any way of getting a matrix of N*N with the information of how many nodes are visited in the shortest path between i and j? Is it an efficient way to calculate it?

This is the one I coded:

```
    def SinglePath(DijkstraPredecesors, i, j):
        length=0
        k=j
        while (i != k) & (k >= 0):
            length+=1
            k = DijkstraPredecesors[i,k]
        return (length)

    def calculate_bi_longerpath(Distancias, DijkstraPredecesors):
        node1=-1
        node2=-1
        n_nodes=0
        distance=-1

        for i in range(0, Distancias.shape[0]):
            print(i)
            for j in range(0, Distancias.shape[1]):
                if(i<j):
                    path=SinglePath(DijkstraPredecesors, i, j)
                    if(path>n_nodes):
                        node1=i
                        node2=j
                        distance=Distancias[i][j]
                        n_nodes=path
        return(node1, node2, distance, n_nodes)


    print("Longest larger path...")
    node1, node2, n_nodes, distance=calculate_bi_longerpath(DijkstraMatrix, DijkstraPredecesors)
    print(node1, node2, n_nodes, distance)
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564308/how-to-calculate-short-path-geodesic-distance-of-adjacency-matrix-csv-python

Comment: you can use `all_pairs_dijkstra_path` instead of `shortest_path`